# VBA Code to show sum as Formula out of named range

Tags: excel, vba

```
    Range("A2").Select
    Dim RowLen1 As String
    RowLen1 = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
    Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3).Select
    Dim SumRangeTot As Range
    Set SumRangeTot = Range("d3:d" & RowLen1)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum(SumRangeTot)"
```

This code shows output as "#Name?. I need output as formula =sum(D3:D24).
So that, i have to copy the formula and make sum total to adjacent columns.

first instance i used the  below code ActiveCell = WorksheetFunction.Sum(SumRangeTot). This i cannot copy, because output is absolute number.

Comment: You have to pass SumRangeTot as a String to the formula, not as Range.

Comment: The correct code would be `Dim SumRangeTot As String`, `SumRangeTot = "D3:D" & RowLen1`

Comment: If i change it string it showing Compile Error : Object Required.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use select ,use the address of SumRangeTot or you can declare it as string if you want.

```
Sub temp()
'Range("A2").Select
    Dim RowLen1 As String
    RowLen1 = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row
   ' Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3).Select
    Dim SumRangeTot As Range
    Set SumRangeTot = Range("d3:d" & RowLen1)
    ActiveCell.Formula = "=Sum(" & SumRangeTot.Address & ")"
End Sub
```

Comment: However this is freezing the reference address. I have to copy the reference to adjacent columns to make sum total

Comment: I found it, i have changed the address to relative cell address by adding (0,0). Thanks for your help

Comment: ActiveCell = "=Sum(" & StartingPoint2.Address(0, 0) & "," & EndofRange2.Address(0, 0) & ")"

Comment: Could you please suggest, whether two address can be clubbed to arrive a range. I have got error with the above code, while clubbing

Comment: @KarthikeyanJayasankar try replacing the `","` with `":"`

Answer (score 0):

you can use just one line of code:

```
Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3).Formula = "=Sum(R3C:R[-1]C)"
```

where you:

- grab the cell to write the formula in (i.e. `Range("A2").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 3)`
- write the formula in R1C1 notation, allowing you to both stick to the column  (the `C` parts) the written cell belongs to and fine tune the starting and ending rows indexes by means of absolute/relative notation (`R3` is row 3, while `R[-1]` stands for 1 row above)